# insertion sort with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, insertion-sort

```
stock={'meat':100,'fish':50,'bread':70, 'milk':35,'chips':15, 'apple':10,'orange':10, 'rice':10,'honey':10,'lemon':10}

def insertionSort( theSeq ):
    n = len( theSeq )

    for i in range(1, n):
       key = theSeq[i]
       pos = i
       while pos > 0 and key < theSeq[pos - 1]:
           theSeq[pos] = theSeq[pos-1]
           pos -= 1

    theSeq[pos] = key


print('Input List:', stock)
insertionSort(stock)
print('Sorted List:', stock)
```

[image: this is my output after i run my codes]

these are my codes and i have been trying to sort my dictionary using insertion sort but i keep running into this error and have no idea what to.

i would like my output to be a list of unsorted dictionary followed by a list of the sorted dictionary

i would appreciate any help i can get
thank you in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. What should be the output at the end?

Comment: my output would be a list of the unsorted dictionary followed by a list of the sorted dictionary

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are trying to implement an insertion sort? You can simply do this: `sorted(stock, key=lambda k: stock[k])` to sort your stock by values.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Also check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) It would help if you asked a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dicts are not sequences (although they preserve insertion order in Python 3.7+). You can convert it to a list:

```
L = list(stock.items())
insertionSort(L)
print(L)
```

... But apparently your algorithm doesn't work, since this is the output:

```
[('lemon', 10), ('meat', 100), ('meat', 100), ('meat', 100), ('meat', 100), ('meat', 100), ('meat', 100), ('milk', 35), ('orange', 10), ('rice', 10)]
```

Comment: hi thanks this is really helpful i  made the proper changes into my algorithm, i am now closer to achieving what i wan to achieve thanks !!

Comment: Note: dict preserve insertion order starting from Python 3.7 and you should not rely on that